# Why do I not get any text when I am binding a string to my XAML using a propertychanged? C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Trying to bind a text via a string to my xaml and use a propertychanged function to change the text depending on the value of an int.
This is my code:

XAML:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding Forename}" />
```

CODE:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null) {

            PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));    
        }

    }

    string info;
    int myInt = 0;

    public string Forename {

        get {
            return info;
        }
        set {
            if (myInt == 0) {
                info = value;
                OnPropertyChanged ("TextOne");
            }

            else if (myInt == 1)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged ("TextTwo");

            }
            else 
            {
                OnPropertyChanged ("TextThree");
            }
        }
    }
```

I get no text now.

Comment: Why are you using "TextOne", "TextTwo", and "TextThree" as the property name? It looks like the name of the property is `Forename`.

Comment: Aha I thought it was there I make the text for my label?

Comment: No... Put the name of the property there. The new text value should just be the property value, so in the setter method you need to always set `info` to the value you want for the property. Then start the OnPropertyChanged. It uses the property name to know which property changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not how `OnPropertyChanged()` works. You shouldn't pass the new text you want displayed as argument, instead you should assign the new text to the info field, and put *the name of the property* as argument.

What `OnPropertyChanged(name)` does is tell the XAML that the Property `name` has changed, on which the XAML will get that property, and update the displayed value accordingly.

```
public string Forename {

    get {
        return info;
    }
    set {
        if (myInt == 0) {
            info = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ("Forename");
        }

        else if (myInt == 1)
        {
            info = "TextTwo";
            OnPropertyChanged ("Forename");

        }
        else 
        {
            info = "TextThree";
            OnPropertyChanged ("Forename");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As you had some questions about what you should put into `protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)`, that function is fine the way it is. When it is called, it will use the `PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged` to let all subsribers to the event know that the property *propertyName* has changed. The XAML `{Binding Forename}` acts as a subscriber/listener for the `PropertyChanged`, and will update it's text as soon as it is told that the property to which it is bound ("Forename") has changed. Which is what happend when you make the call `OnPropertyChanged("Forename")`.

**Edit 2**
It seems you may have forgotten to assign your DataContext
In the code-behind of your XAML (will be named something like mainwindow.xaml.cs)

```
InitializeComponent();
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
DataContext = vm;
vm.Forename = "TestString"
```

And move the Forename-code stuff into a seperate class, name ViewModel. Like this:

```
public class ViewModel{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        var changed = PropertyChanged;
        if (changed != null) {
            PropertyChanged (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (propertyName));    
        }

    }

string info;
int myInt = 0;

public string Forename {

    get {
        return info;
    }
    set {
        if (myInt == 0) {
            info = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ("Forename");
        }

        else if (myInt == 1)
        {
            info = "TextTwo";
            OnPropertyChanged ("Forename");

        }
        else 
        {
            info = "TextThree";
            OnPropertyChanged ("Forename");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: in my protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(name), should i replace name with value? I cannot find either value or the Forname strings

Comment: since the `OnPropertyChanged` call is the same, you can move it to after the `if{}else{}`.

Comment: i meant on this one: "protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ()" what should i add inside there?

Comment: @William.John, when I say `OnPropertyChanged(name)` I just mean that the argument in `OnPropertyChanged()` should be the name of the property, in this case "Forename".

Your `protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ()` is fine the way it is, as far as I can see.

Comment: I get no text. it is very weird. i use ur code + my protected virtual void + in xaml i bind Forname

Comment: Do you bind to "Forname" or "Forename"? Be careful when binding that the path you bind to is spelled _exactly_ the same as the Property (and that you use the _exact_ same spelling when firing OnPropertyChanged("Forename"))

Comment: I use Forename so it matches.. Still nothing. Maybe it is a stupid mistake i have done somewhere. I copy ur exact code though + bind it via xaml. (and the protected virtual void is the same)

Comment: @William.John Did the binding work once or not at all? i.e. did you set the `DataContext` correctly?

Comment: Don't forget, that in order for the whole `set{...}` block to trigger, you have to somewhere in your code use `Forename="Some Value"`. The `set` part of a property only triggers when you assign a value to it (hence the name, "set")

Comment: InitializeComponent ();

   Forename = "Test";

I still get no text when I bind it to my label

Comment: No the binding has not worked yet. I bind a string to my label text, that is it. am i missing something?

Comment: it seems to me that you need to set a `BindingContext`, which is explained [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/).

Comment: I've added an additional edit to try and demonstrate how to set up a DataContext, but I suggest you follow a [DataBinding tutorial to learn more](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/) . Or as @Default said, follow the Xamarin Binding tutorial if you're building a xamarin app, though I'd suggest starting out with just a plain old desktop WPF application if you're still learning the basics about databindin. (but that's just my opinion)

Comment: Thanks alot! I will take a look when I am home. (1hour-ish)

Comment: I cant' find Datacontext, googling and it looks like it needs using system.linq; i have it enabled though but cant find it

Comment: I get the binding to work now atleast. "vm.Forename = "TestString";" works. but it does not change the value depending on the vale of the int

Comment: i write in my log if i reach any of the int values but i cannot reach any of the set values in my public string Forename

Comment: still problems, but i had so many different errors and you guided me the right way. appreciate ur help. giving u the correct answer of course.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code I suspect that you made the most popular mistake in `Binding`. You are *not* raising changes for correct property. The idea is that XAML somehow must know that property changed to update the UI - so instead running in tight loop and check if property value is different than this on the screen Microsoft come with idea of `delegate` that named `PropertyChanged`. Mostly used in getter/setters.

You have to be very careful in using this delegate because until version 4 of .NET Framework parameter for delegate was `string` - the *name* of the property. Later version of .NET Framework bring the special attribute [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) - here is example: [Jesse Liberty](http://jesseliberty.com/2012/06/28/c-5making-inotifypropertychanged-easier/)

In you case you rising the property changed event but in parameter you sending names of properties that does not exist :( You should send `OnPropertyChanged("Forename")` only.

Comment: protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ("Forename") //error: Unexpect symbol 'Forename'

Comment: You should **NOT** change the method definition from `protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)` to `protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged ("Forename")`, you pass the string "Forename" as parameter when you call the method. (in the `set` part of your Property)